# Nuxt js how dispatch action in store and change state

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

i have look some articles about it but i didn’t understand so much

here is my problem :

i have a component in nuxt

```
<a @click="openMenu">Open Menu</a>
<div v-if="isUserNav"> ...  </div>
```

basically i want on click change to state of isUserNav to true via vuex store

here in my component i can access to state

```
import {
mapState
} from ‘vuex’

export default {
    computed: {
        ...mapState({
            isUserNav: state => state.isUserNav
        })
    },
    methods: {
        openMenu () {
            this.$store.commit('openMenu')
        },
    }
}
```

here is vuex store:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'


const createStore = () => {
    return new Vuex.Store({
        state: () => ({
            // USER NAV COMPONENT
            isUserNav: false,
            testData: "Hello"
        }),
        actions: {
            async openMenu() {
              this.state.isUserNav = true;
            }
          }
    })
}

export default createStore
```

there is i can’t run action exactly i can access to action but it giving

```
[vuex] unknown mutation type: openMenu
```

error in console.

where i make mistake and what i need to do ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your mistake lies in:

`this.$store.commit('openMenu')`

which triggers not an `action` but a `mutation`. You don't have that mutation so therefore you get the message `[vuex] unknown mutation type: openMenu`.

To trigger an action you need to dispatch with `dispatch`:

`this.$store.dispatch('openMenu')`

But your action is not correct written and won't work and actions are not for mutating the state directly. They commit mutations which then mutate the state.

#### Solution

So in your case here it seems to be enough with a mutation so rewriting your action to a mutation should help to achieve your goal.

```
mutations: {
  openMenu(state) {
    state.isUserNav = true
  }
}
```

Have a look into mutations and actions in the vuex docs:

- https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html
- https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html

which describe both and their use cases quite good.